# div moving when input is auto focussed on load

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've been struggling with this for hours.

I've stripped down my problem as much as possible. I have a div inside a form that has a left margin the same width of the form, and the form has overflow hidden (I want to hide the div). If I fire a focus on the first input of the form after load something strange happens. The div seems to center in the form (using the combined total of div width + div left margin). I have no idea why it moves at all? I can't see any input properties apart from outline that change at all?

Live example here: http://jsfiddle.net/fQurc/12/ I've added a timeout so you can see what I mean.

I'd really appreciate any ideas? Thanks

Comment: What is the visual effect you want to achieve?

Comment: I've created a slider which slides in/out various stages of a sign up process which are retrieved by ajax - the current stage slides out to the left - new stage slides in from the right. I've simplified it down to the core issue in the example above - which is jolting the slide effect about.

Comment: Why not focus on the input AFTER sliding it back ?

Comment: I've done similar effects in the past. I find that `float: left`, is not a good way of doing it. Better is to set `position: relative` on a container div and then `position: absolute` on an inner. The inner would then be `width: 600px` and set `left: -300px` when it is moved all the way left (skip the margin).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the browser forcing the input field into view so that the user can see it. If you change the margin-left to 250px so that part of the field is visible, you will notice that the effect doesn't happen.

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/fQurc/37/

If you need to use an input field that should not be visible; I would advise using:

`<input type="hidden" />`

I hope this helps!

Comment: +1 I agree, browser will show the field even if you style it with display:none, it will override all styles to show you the field, because there is no sense to focus input field if you want it to be invisible (if user could enter some data into invisible field I would consider it security flaw)

Comment: Great thanks : ) All that was needed was to wait until I'd slid the form in to focus.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem was the `overflow:hidden;` on the form

remove it, and the input will not move :

http://jsfiddle.net/fQurc/23/

Comment: Sure, but I want it hidden : )

Comment: Don't use the overflow to hide it, it's not a good way to do it ... only hide the input as dSquared said